# Java screenshot taken after hidding parent's window

Tags: java, swing, screenshot

I'm trying (and achieving) to get a screenshot with:

```
robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage biScreen = robot.createScreenCapture(rectScreenSize);
ia.setImage(biScreen);
```

This works great, but this action is called from a JButton inside a JPanel. When I click the button, before calling my ScreenCapture class, I try to hide the JPanel without success using these:

```
super.getTopLevelAncestor().setVisible(false); 
super.getTopLevelAncestor().validate();
super.getTopLevelAncestor().revalidate();
super.getTopLevelAncestor().repaint();

ScreenCapture capture = new ScreenCapture("Screenshot's title", p); //create capture window with screenshot taken
```

How can I hide my JPanel before taking the screenshot? At the moment I'm getting my desktop's screenshot with my JPanel always visible.

Cheers!

Comment: how is your JButton added to your JPanel ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside of a button action, you're invoked inside the EDT ([Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html))

If you call `setVisible(false)` from there, you'll have to wait until this event you just sent has been processed by the window - before that the window is still visible.

I'd suggest you either delay the screenshot with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or (if that happens too early as well) start a `Timer` with a delay of half a second and do your screenshot once the timer fires.

Comment: Thanks, Jan! I think this is it! :-) I'm working with invokeLater() to solve the problem.